# click event in class in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, click

I am trying to create a click event in order to easily see coordinates on my grid. I have been following the effbot tutorial, but it doesn't seem to work within my class. here is what I have:

```
class Keyboard(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, press):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.press = press
        self.createWidgets()
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.click)

    def click(event):
        print("clicked at", event.x, event.y)
```

When I run this and click somewhere it says:

```
"TypeError: click() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`click` is a method of the class `Keyboard`.  This means that it will always be passed an implicit first argument (usually called `self`) which is a reference to the class itself.

You need to define `click` like so:

```
def click(self, event):
```

Otherwise, `event` will receive the argument for `self` and the argument that should be for `event` will be left over.

Here is a reference on `self` in Python: [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)

Answer (score 2):

You are defining class function `click` so you have to pass first argument as `self` class object

so please change it

```
class Keyboard(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, press):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.press = press
        self.createWidgets()
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.click)

    def click(self, event):
        print("clicked at", event.x, event.y)
```